# QTableWidget column resize event

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I want to know whether a column of a QTableWidget is being resized by mouse. How can I emit a signal whenever any of the columns is resized?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Column resizing is performed by the horizontal `QHeaderView`.  Access it by calling `QTableWidget::horizontalHeader() const`, and the signal you are interested in is `QHeaderView::sectionResized(int logicalIndex, int oldSize, int newSize)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @cmannett85. It's great to have a working answer.