# PyQt: receive QTableWidget column resize signal

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I'm using PyQt. I want to detect when a user resizes columns in a QTableWidget.

[This answer for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648999/qtablewidget-column-resize-event) suggests that the signal will be `QTableWidget.horizontalHeader.sectionResized`, but that gives this error:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sectionResized'
```

How can I connect in Python to the `sectionResized` signal?

Comment: Try `QTableWidget.horizontalHeader().sectionResized`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.